# How can I Traverse through a Tree with Multiple childs?

Tags: c#, tree, spatial

I'm currently playing around with partioning 2D Space.

[Tree with Rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFBZQ.png)

This is my Tree

```
    private class TreeNode
    {
        public Rectangle region;
        public TreeNode childQ1;
        public TreeNode childQ2;
        public TreeNode childQ3;
        public TreeNode childQ4;

        public TreeNode(Rectangle region)
        {
            this.region = region;
        }
    }
```

This is how I'm partioning the Tree, I debugged it and everything looks fine

```
public class RegionTree
{
    private class TreeNode
    {
        public Rectangle region;
        public TreeNode childQ1;
        public TreeNode childQ2;
        public TreeNode childQ3;
        public TreeNode childQ4;

        public TreeNode(Rectangle region)
        {
            this.region = region;
        }
    }

    TreeNode root;

    public RegionTree(int RegionWidth, int RegionHeight, byte depth)
    {
        root = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(0, 0, RegionWidth, RegionHeight));
        GenerateNodes(root, depth);
    }

    private void GenerateNodes(TreeNode node, int depth)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        {
            int halfWidth = node.region.Width / 2;
            int halfHeight = node.region.Height / 2;

            TreeNode childQ1 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X, node.region.Y, halfWidth, halfHeight));
            node.childQ1 = childQ1;
            TreeNode childQ2 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X + halfWidth, node.region.Y, halfWidth, halfHeight));
            node.childQ2 = childQ2;
            TreeNode childQ3 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X, node.region.Y + halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight));
            node.childQ3 = childQ3;
            TreeNode childQ4 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X + halfWidth, node.region.Y + halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight));
            node.childQ4 = childQ4;

            GenerateNodes(childQ1, i);
            GenerateNodes(childQ2, i);
            GenerateNodes(childQ3, i);
            GenerateNodes(childQ4, i);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to go through all nodes and subnodes and Draw the rectangles but need some help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look at the quad tree Generator, the loop inside the generator is recreating the child node objects and throwing away the generated objects.  So for iteration 0, 4 new objects and subsequent child objects are created.  For iteration 1, those objects are overwritten with new objects while the previous values are garbage collected.  What you want to do is start off:

```
    private void GenerateNodes(TreeNode node, int depth)
    {
        if(depth < 0) return;
        int halfWidth = node.region.Width / 2;
        int halfHeight = node.region.Height / 2;

        TreeNode childQ1 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X, node.region.Y, halfWidth, halfHeight));
        node.childQ1 = childQ1;
        TreeNode childQ2 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X + halfWidth, node.region.Y, halfWidth, halfHeight));
        node.childQ2 = childQ2;
        TreeNode childQ3 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X, node.region.Y + halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight));
        node.childQ3 = childQ3;
        TreeNode childQ4 = new TreeNode(new Rectangle(node.region.X + halfWidth, node.region.Y + halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight));
        node.childQ4 = childQ4;

        GenerateNodes(childQ1, depth - 1);
        GenerateNodes(childQ2, depth - 1);
        GenerateNodes(childQ3, depth - 1);
        GenerateNodes(childQ4, depth - 1);
    }
}
```

Ok, now that we have a working generator, the way to walk these leaves uses similar code.  You can walk them differently, depending on what order you want to print.

```
    private void WalkNodes(TreeNode node)
    {   
        if(node == null) return;
        //do something here will write root tracing to the left, 
        //which will draw your rectangles from the outside in, 
        //finishing each bottom left before starting the next
        WalkNodes(node.childQ1);
        WalkNodes(node.childQ2);
        WalkNodes(node.childQ3);
        WalkNodes(node.childQ4);
        //do something here to traverse the tree from the last 
        //leaf back to the first, which will draw your rectangles 
        //from the inside to out, finishing the right upper first
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

BFS, DFS, Euler Traversal etc, any of these will do it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: I learned this in my first Semester of CS and tought that I would never need this stuff again. I was wrong.